# Rails Carrier Wave with JQuery Uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jquery, carrierwave

I am using Rails Carrier Wave with JQuery Upload like on this [rails tutorial](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Rails-setup-for-V5), but I am having an error when I hit the upload button :

```
Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse
```

Any advise/suggestions are much appriciated.

Comment: edited your post : please use plain text instead of image links, especially with such short error messages ( if your link breaks, your question won't be understandable anymore ). Moreover, it will be simpler to help you if you give more information, like actual code (ui scripts, controller action...)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Why not try [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)?

#### Step 1

Add `gem 'carrier_wave'` to you Gemfile.

#### Step 2

Save this code to `/lib/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb`:

```
require 'rack/utils'

class FlashSessionCookieMiddleware
  def initialize app, session_key = '_session_id'
    @app = app
    @session_key = session_key
  end

  def call env
    if env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ /^(Adobe|Shockwave) Flash/
      request = Rack::Request.new env
      env['HTTP_COOKIE'] = [@session_key, request.params[@session_key]].join('=').freeze unless request.params[@session_key].nil?
      env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = "#{request.params['_http_accept']}".freeze unless request.params['_http_accept'].nil?
    end

    @app.call env
  end
end
```

#### Step 3

Edit `session_store.rb` and add this code to the end of file:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before(
  ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore,
  FlashSessionCookieMiddleware,
  Rails.application.config.session_options[:key]
)
```

#### Step 4

Download [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/download/) and unzip it.

#### Step 5

1. Copy `jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js` and `swfobject.js` to
   `/app/assets/javascripts` if you use Rails 3.1 or later; to
   `/public/javascripts` if you use Rails 3.0 or an earlier version.
2. Copy `uploadify.swf` and `cancel.png` to `/app/assets/images/` or
   `/public/images`.
3. Copy `uploadify.css` to `/app/assets/stylesheets/` or
   `/public/stylesheets`.

#### Step 6

Edit your application.js and insert below:

```
//= require swfobject
//= require jquery.uploadify
```

#### Step 7

In you upload page, add this:

```
<input id="uploadify" name="uploadify" type="file"/>
```

#### Step 8

Add this code to you upload script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  <% key = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key] %>
  var uploadify_script_data = {};
  var csrf_param = $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content');
  var csrf_token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
  uploadify_script_data[csrf_param] = encodeURI(encodeURIComponent(csrf_token));
  uploadify_script_data['<%= key %>'] = '<%= cookies[key] %>';

  $('#uploadify').uploadify({
    uploader        : '/assets/uploadify.swf',
    script          : '/photos',
    cancelImg       : '/images/cancel.png',
    auto            : true,
    multi           : true,
    removeCompleted     : true,
    scriptData      : uploadify_script_data,
    onComplete      : function(event, ID, fileObj, doc, data) {
    }
  });
});
```

#### Step 9

Write your controller like this:

```
def create
  @photo = Photo.new image: params[:file_data]
  @photo.save
end
```

**Note:** This was tested with Uploadify 2.1.4.

Comment: I suppose because CarrierWave doesn't take 8 steps to get working :p

Comment: Can you expand on Step 9? I'm getting a HTTP Error. How do I know it is returning correctly?

Comment: Seems like the free version only supports flash, therefore won't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was also using uploadify, but this JS plugin does not require Flash and is more aethetically pleasing aka "prettier". I created a demo app out of some examples,

Its a simple case and you can learn a lot from it:

https://github.com/jalagrange/bootstrap_uploader

Hope this helps!