# Not able to find the flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb in lib file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uploadify, carrierwave

I ve followed this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363698/rails-carrier-wave-with-jquery-uploader) for using carrierwave and uploadify but i am not being able to do that. 
i m using rails 3.2.11. Can u please help me im not able to find the `flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb` file in lib? Is this file to be created? Since ive created this file in the lib folder and add that snippet of code in `session_sore.rb`. And when i m restarting my server it is giving this error `uninitialized constant FlashSessionCookieMiddleware (NameError)`. What can be done in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Check `application.rb` for containing this line:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```