# uploading error when using carrierwave and uploadify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, uploadify, carrierwave

i was trying for `uploadify` with `carrierwave` to support `multiple file upload` but it is giving me this error `GET http://localhost:3000/users/uploadify.swf?preventswfcaching=1361694618739`.
Basically i ve one `model` named as `user`. For single upload it is working fine with carrierwave but for multiple file it is not.

I ve followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363698/rails-carrier-wave-with-jquery-uploader) tutorial.
In `users/_form.rb`

```
<p>
<%= f.label "Upload Images"%>
<%= f.file_field :image, :multiple => true %>
</p>

<script type= "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 <% key = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key] %>
  var uploadify_script_data = {};
  var csrf_param = $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content');
  var csrf_token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
  uploadify_script_data[csrf_param] = encodeURI(encodeURIComponent(csrf_token));
  uploadify_script_data['<%= key %>'] = '<%= cookies[key] %>';

  $('#user_image').uploadify({
  uploader        : '<%= asset_path("uploadify.swf")%>',
  script          : '/images',
  cancelImg       : '<%= asset_path("uploadify-cancel.png")%>',
  auto            : true,
  multi           : true,
  removeCompleted     : true,
  scriptData      : uploadify_script_data,
  onComplete      : function(event, ID, fileObj, doc, data) {
  }
  });  
 });
</script>
```

I m using mongoid so the model is like this

```
class User
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :name, type: String
 field :description, type: String
 field :image, type: String

   mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader 
 end
```

I m not getting what is the error. Please help me out.

Comment: You've only posted the GET-request, not the actual error. Please post the error.

Comment: it is the error i m getting in js console. Actually that browse files button is not working.

Comment: Please understand that `GET http://localhost:3000/users/uploadify.swf?preventswfcaching=1361694618739` is not an error, it's simply a statement. Please give us the actual error.

Comment: Actually I ve done copy paste for uploadify to work. And its kind a mess over there. Can u explain me how to integrate uploadify with carrierwave.? That would be very kind of u. thanks :)

Comment: Uploadify and carrierwave not working what? didn't get that you need present the error to us perhaps then we can help u better

Comment: See i m not getting any error in the logs. What exactly happening is that the upload button is not working. When i click on that button then that line get printed in the JS console. As i ve already told since i ve done copy paste there is a mess all over in the code. May be the paths in the script are not correct. Thats why i was asking steps for integrating carrierwave with uploadify for multiple file uploads.

Comment: @ahmadhamza did you get solution for it?

Comment: @shrikant1712: i left it. :(

Comment: If your file is called _form.rb you should change it to _form.html.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete solution for multiple image uploads with Carrierwave:
To do just follow these steps.

```
rails new multiple_image_upload_carrierwave
```

In gem file

```
gem 'carrierwave'
```

Then run the following

```
bundle install
rails generate uploader Avatar
```

Create post scaffold

```
rails generate scaffold post title:string
```

Create post_attachment scaffold

```
rails generate scaffold post_attachment post_id:integer avatar:string
```

Then run

```
rake db:migrate
```

In post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :post_attachments
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_attachments
end
```

In post_attachment.rb

```
class PostAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
   mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
   belongs_to :post
end
```

In post_controller.rb

```
def show
   @post_attachments = @post.post_attachments.all
end

def new
   @post = Post.new
   @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.build
end

def create
   @post = Post.new(post_params)

   respond_to do |format|
     if @post.save
       params[:post_attachments]['avatar'].each do |a|
         @post_attachment = @post.post_attachments.create!(:avatar => a, :post_id => @post.id)
       end
       format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
     else
       format.html { render action: 'new' }
     end
   end
 end

 private
   def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, post_attachments_attributes: [:id, :post_id, :avatar])
   end
```

In views/posts/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@post, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :title %><br>
     <%= f.text_field :title %>
   </div>

   <%= f.fields_for :post_attachments do |p| %>
     <div class="field">
       <%= p.label :avatar %><br>
       <%= p.file_field :avatar, :multiple => true, name: "post_attachments[avatar][]" %>
     </div>
   <% end %>

   <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

To edit an attachment and list of attachment for any post. In views/posts/show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<% @post_attachments.each do |p| %>
  <%= image_tag p.avatar_url %>
  <%= link_to "Edit Attachment", edit_post_attachment_path(p) %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

Update form to edit an attachment views/post_attachments/_form.html.erb

```
<%= image_tag @post_attachment.avatar %>
<%= form_for(@post_attachment) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :avatar %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Modify update method in post_attachment_controller.rb

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post_attachment.update(post_attachment_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @post_attachment.post, notice: 'Post attachment was successfully updated.' }
    end 
  end
end
```

In rails 3 no need to define strong parameters and as you can define attribute_accessible in both the model and accept_nested_attribute to post model because attribute accessible is deprecated in rails 4.

For edit an attachment we cant modify all the attachments at a time. so we will replace attachment one by one, or you can modify as per your rule, Here I just show you how to update any attachment.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem, or do you need more information?

Comment: No worries Ahmad! Glad I could help.